# how to run commands on different servers with different users

Tags: ansible

I have to check the status of my databases which runs on many servers with different user ids for example: on server1 it runs with user1 on server2 it runs with user2 etc. In my playbook, I have the code to check the database status but don't know how to run this on different hosts and different user ids.

I have written playbook which can check the database status but doesn't know how to make this run with different user ids on different servers.

Playbook:

```
---
- hosts: all
  become: true
  become_user: db2inst1
  tasks:
   - name: Start DB2
     command: /home/db2inst1/sqllib/adm/db2_ps
```

Inventory:

```
[db-servers]
192.168.4.30
```

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at the ["Connecting to hosts: behavioral inventory parameters"](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html#connecting-to-hosts-behavioral-inventory-parameters) section of Ansible Docs. It explains all the variables you can set to modify Ansible's behavior on each host.

In your case, you are going to have to define the `ansible_user` variable to use on each `host`, and the corresponding authentication details (passwords, ssh keys, etc.)

You can configure these variables on your inventory files. For example, suppose that you need to use the user `root` for some server, and `ubuntu` for another. You can configure your `playbook` like this.

```
[db-servers]
192.168.4.30 ansible_user=root
192.178.4.31 ansible_user=ubuntu
```

I hope it helps.